# wxWidgets: Are there functions for a path manipulation? (Split to subdirs, join, ...)

Tags: wxwidgets

Having a path in a wxString variable, how do you append a subdirectory? Are there any specific functions for working with paths?

For those of you who know the Python language, there are nice functions like `os.path.join("sub1", "sub2", "sub3"...)` that joins the `subX` parts using the OS specific separator, and the `os.path.split(path)` that splits the path to the directory and the last name. The `os.path.join()` is nice even in situations when you are sure what separator can be used.

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

P.S. I am interested in the lastest wxWidgets version (2.9.4+).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wxFilename does what you need.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_name.html

so, for example

```
wxFileName fname;
fname.AppendDir("sub1");
fname.AppendDir("sub2");
fname.SetName("test");
fname.SetExt("txt");
```

will create on windows

```
sub1\sub2\test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice. Sorry for the simple questions. I could not find it in the time. :)